# Filtering a dataframe by variable number of criteria?

Tags: r, dataframe

Say that I have a dataframe with columns 'a', 'b', 'c'. Is it possible to filter the dataframe with a variable number of criteria?

Instead of:

```
df[df$a == "chicken" | df$a == "cow" | df$a == "dog" | ...,]
```

Is there something like:

```
df[df$a == c("chicken", "cow", "dog"),]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%in%`

```
 v1 <- c("chicken", "cow", "dog")
 df[df$a %in% v1,]
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df <- data.frame(a= sample(c('chicken', 'cow', 'dog', 'elephant',
  'cat'), 20, replace=TRUE), b=rnorm(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use match or grepl

Using Match:

`df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("cow","dog","cat"))
p<-c("cow","dog")
df1<- df[match(p,df$b),]`

Using grepl: 
`df1<- df[grepl(paste(p, collapse="|") , df$b),]`

Comment: I think that match() only gets the first time those elements appear, and grepl() would also match elements where it is nested? i.e. "cow" in "cowel" This is a helpful start though!

Answer (score 0):

```
> df <- expand.grid(A1=(1:3)*10,A2=1:3,A3=c("Chicken","dog"))
> df
   A1 A2      A3
1  10  1 Chicken
2  20  1 Chicken
3  30  1 Chicken
4  10  2 Chicken
5  20  2 Chicken
6  30  2 Chicken
7  10  3 Chicken
8  20  3 Chicken
9  30  3 Chicken
10 10  1     dog
11 20  1     dog
12 30  1     dog
13 10  2     dog
14 20  2     dog
15 30  2     dog
16 10  3     dog
17 20  3     dog
18 30  3     dog
```

Use Subset with the condition

```
> x <- with(df, (A2 == 2 | A3 == "dog"))
> subset(df, x)
   A1 A2      A3
4  10  2 Chicken
5  20  2 Chicken
6  30  2 Chicken
10 10  1     dog
11 20  1     dog
12 30  1     dog
13 10  2     dog
14 20  2     dog
15 30  2     dog
16 10  3     dog
17 20  3     dog
18 30  3     dog
```

Comment: I'm not sure this saves me any text though?

Comment: `subset` doesn't need `with`.  `subset(df, A2==2|A3=='dog')` would be enough.